# Android dialog over lock screen

Tags: android

I am design a apps about alarm clock.

How can I display a dialog even the phone is locked?

I don't want the phone to be unlock. I just want it to display some text on the phone. User need to unlock the phone by themselves on hand for more information.

It is not necessary to use dialog. All I want is just some text to be display.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

on your activity, add those flags:

```
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
}
```

Comment: When to excute this? onstart? Can this be use in service?

Comment: it's a method, inside your activity. it overrides something your activity already has. about the service, no.

Comment: This doesn't work on android 5 or newer

Comment: @trampster Can you please show a tiny, minimal, sample project? Maybe on Github ? I'd like to try it out and see how to change it.

Comment: @trampster I can't confirm your issue. Tested on Android 7.