# Screen unlocking in the alarm

Tags: android, screen, alarmmanager, android-alarms, unlock

I have alarm application. When alarm goes - appears dialogue window, music etc.
How can i show this dialogue window even if screen unlocked?
How pgrogammatically unlock the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I've already found this post, ehich may may have answer to both of your questions.

[How to show dialog even if the screen is locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727278/how-to-show-dialog-even-if-the-screen-is-locked)

Hope it help